# Google cloud container deployment version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google Cloud container deployment. I can't find a consistent way to always get the latest version of the container image.

In this page, the latest container version is 'container-vm-v20150112' 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms
changelog is on January 12, 2015

However, in this following page, the version is 'container-vm-v20150317'
https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/create-container-deployment
or https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/create-advanced-deployment

I was wondering if I in the future we could automatically point to the latest 'container-vm-latest'. Where could I find out the latest version? Is there one git repo I could look to the version and changelog?

cheers
Leonardo Correa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms, you can find a list of all available versions by running `gcloud compute images list --project google-containers`.

If you just pass `--image=container-vm` it should be an alias to the latest version, but we haven't always been as diligent as we should be keeping this up to date.

Comment: passing --image=container-vm may work for gcloud command line VM creation. It doesn't seem to work for Deployment Manager. I based on this example here: 
https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/create-advanced-deployment

Comment: It looks like for Deployment Manager you may need to specify the full image URL rather than a short name. So you need to list the available versions, pick the one you want (likely the latest) and then put in the full URL.